# Converting byte type file to workable format in python

Tags: python, class, byte, sequence, analysis

I have to read the table in below link(html page) into a dict() and then work on it. However, with the below code I gave, the table still looks clumsy and I do not understand from where to start working to make it a dictionary of codon sequence(e.g. AGU) to respective Amino Acid. Any way to make it look better? May be something like a DataFrame or any other suggestions? Please help. Thanks.

```
link = "http://www.kazusa.or.jp/codon/cgi-bin/showcodon.cgi?species=9606&aa=1&style=N"
f = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
myfile = f.read()
s = myfile.decode()
s.strip(" ")
```

Comment: What is the raw data received and the desired output? Give some examples and show us what you have tried so far to process the data!

Comment: The raw data is that html link only. I have to make dictionary out of it. Above code I wrote to open the data in jupyter notebook and ultimately converted it to class 'str'. It comes as a one big paragraph. I just wanted to know if there is a better way to open and manage it.

Comment: Here on Stack Overflow everything related to the question has to be included in the question itself. No links and no screenshots.

Comment: I am sorry but my assignment is to work on this html file only and hence I gave that link.

Answer (score 0):

If you have looked at the page `http://www.kazusa.or.jp/codon/cgi-bin/showcodon.cgi?species=9606&aa=1&style=N` you would have noticed that it contains not just the codon sequence you want, but **a lot** of HTML around it. To extract just the codons, the best way is likely to use BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
link = "http://www.kazusa.or.jp/codon/cgi-bin/showcodon.cgi?species=9606&aa=1&style=N"
f = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
myfile = f.read()
s = myfile.decode()
codons = BeautifulSoup(s).find('pre').text
```

Now you should probably process this string further to get the form you want - dict, list, dataframe, whatever. Assuming you just want a dict, since you mentioned a dictionary:

```
import re
codons_dict = { t[0]: t[1] for t in sorted(re.findall(r'(\w{3})\s+\w\s+(\S+)\s+\S+\s+[(]\d+[)]', codons)) }
```

Comment: You are awesome. I spent the whole day yesterday figuring it out. "BeautifulSoup" was no where mentioned. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Hi..what if I want to print codon and probabilities given in first and third column of the html page? Also I need all 64 codon(triplets) even those where amino acid formed are indicated as (*). I  am giving the code as -"{ t[0]: t[2] for t in re.findall(r'(\w{3})\s+(\w)*(\W+)', codons) }" but only codons are printed and not the probabilities using this code. Please help.

Comment: Change `\w` to `\S` to match any non-space character (not just letter), including `*`.

Comment: Not working. I wanted dictionary like this.."GCG': '0.11', 'GAG': '0.58', 'GGG': '0.25', 'UAA': '0.30'" where "UAA" has * but would still have been included in the dictionary along with others. My code gives something like this-"GCG':  ' ', 'GAG': ' ', 'GGG': '  ', 'UAA': "*".

Comment: Have a look at the modified answer (just the last line).